# For any positive real number $x>0$, there exist a positive integer N such that $x>1/N>0$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, cauchy-sequences

I am trying to prove the following:
For any positive real number $x>0$, there exist a positive integer N such that $x>1/N>0$.

What I know is:
since x is a real number, it can be expressed as the formal limit of a Cauchy sequence
$$x:=LIM (b_n)_{n=1}^\inf$$ 
since $x>0$, the sequence $(b_n)$ is bounded away from zero, i.e. $|b_n|>c$, $c>0$
Also, since $(b_n)$ is Cauchy then its bounded by M ($|b_n|\leq M$)

However, I dont know how to further proceed. Would appreciate your help.

Comment: I believe this refers to the *Archimedean property* of real numbers.

Comment: Archimedean property solved it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Let x and $\epsilon$ be any positive real numbers,
there exist M such that $M\epsilon>x$. choose $\epsilon=1$, then $$\frac{1}{M}<x$$ $$x>\frac{1}{M}>0$$

Comment: If I take $\epsilon = 1$ I get $M>x$. How did you get $1/M < x$?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**
$$x>0$$ There will be infinitely many positive integers $A$ such that $$A>\frac{1}{x}.$$

Comment: Yes, I would guess so...